# Is there a way to copy the variation image to the other if color variation is the same?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I imported products in my woocommerce store, every product have multiple variations, we have just one image for every variation.

So my idea is:

Check if the product has a variation image and copy it to all other variations that have the same color attribute. Is it possible to do it massively via SQL or php?

Comment: Instead of running the task of assigning the product image to all its variations, I would set up a filter that would show the product image if the variation doesn't have one.

Since WC will show a placeholder image if a product (or variation) doesn't have an image, I would use that filter
woocommerce_placeholder_img_src
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-the-placeholder-image/
-Set up the filter, only products with no image will get in the filter
-Check if product is a variation
-If it's a variation, get the original product and the source of its image
-Return that src

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution I'll check into it immediately!